# How to check if element there is in DOM react?

Tags: reactjs

I am using portal in React and want to get access to elements from other components.

For example, I have components with:

```
// here I want to put some content via portal
<div id='buttons'></div>
```

That is my component where I create portal

```
  const elem = document.getElementById('buttons');

     return (
    <div className="block-mainContent">
      {isLoading ?
        <Loader />
        :
        <Table
          data={memoCustomers}
          headers={headers}
          actionRender={actionRender}
          showCheckbox
          onSelect={onSelect}
          onSelectAll={onSelectAll}
          selectedRows={Array.from(selectedIds)}
        />}
      <Modal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={() => dispatch(closeModalAction())}
        content={editModalContent()}
      />
      {!!elem && createPortal(<button>test</button>, elem)} // !!! here is my portal !!!
    </div>
  );
```

My problem is  **I get such error "Target container is not a DOM element**

As I understand, the problem happens because I try to get an element  before it is mounted and as result I get null.

How to check if my div elemen exists and then to create portal?

I try to use different approaches. In the code above I use that

```
 {!!elem && createPortal(<button>test</button>, elem)} 

// here I check If element exists it will return true and portal will be created

// but it works a bit wrong. Describe it below
```

It helps to remove error, but my portal starts working only at the second render. I mean, after loading my page there is no portal. If only I make smth on the page, rerender happens and portal appears.

I tried else

```
 const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true)
  }, []);

{mounted && createPortal(<button>test</button>, elem)}

// here I create portal in the first render via useEffect and
```

But it throws the same error. No one of my ideas works.

If you know how to fix it, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create your buttons element to the parent component which of you need to create portal, or html body in `index.html`.

For example

```
// index.html in public folder if 
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id='buttons'></div>
  </body>
  ...
</html>
```

or in your parent component without using useRef and follow your previous coding style

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const PortalContainer = () => {
  return <div id={"buttons"}></div>;
};

const Home = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const [portalElement, setPortalElement] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    const portalContainer = document.getElementById("buttons");
    if (portalContainer)
      setPortalElement(createPortal(<button>test</button>, portalContainer));
  }, [mounted]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Portal Testing</h2>
      <PortalContainer />
      {portalElement}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `useRef` for the portal DOM node.

```js
// parent component

const buttonsContainerRef = useRef();

<div ref={buttonsContainerRef}>{/* buttons */}</div>
<MainContent buttonsContainer={buttonsContainerRef.current} />

// main content

{buttonsContainer ? createPortal(<button />, buttonsContainer) : null}
```

Comment: It is possible to do that without ref? 

My element div is in separate component. And to get this ref via props is very inconvenient.